# Mapping an observable response as an array of custom interfaces in Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, observable, mapping

I have an `Observable keyValue(): Observable<{[id: number]: string;}>;`

The Observable's argument is:

```
{
    [id: number]: string;
}
```

As you can see the second argument haven't name

Now one result of my previous Observable was:

```
{1: 'Bad', 2: 'Good', 3: 'Worst', 4: 'Best', 5: 'Mean'}
```

I need to translate as an array of:

```
interface NumberKeyValue {
   id: number;
   value: string;
 }
```

I was trying with:

```
.keyValue()
  .pipe(
    map((kv) => {
      console.log(kv);
      const jsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(kv));
      console.log(jsonObject);
      const nkvArray: NumberKeyValue[] = [];
      for (const item of jsonObject) {
        console.log(item);
        const nkv: NumberKeyValue = {
          id: 8,                                        //How to catch the id number?
          value: 'empty',                               //How to catch the string?
        };
        nkvArray.push(nkv);
      }
      return nkvArray;
    })
  )
  .subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

After of previous code I got:

```
TypeError: jsonObject is not iterable
    at MapSubscriber.project (template-sms.facade.ts:295)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:46)
    at TapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (switchMap.js:70)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
    at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

First and mainly Question:How I can to translate to one Array of my `NumberKeyValue` interface?

Secondly: Is there a name for this type representation `{[id: number]: string;}`?

Answer (score 0):

The object type is indeed not iterable, but you can use `Object.keys` to get an array of keys that you can then use to project the data in the desired form:

```
.keyValue()
  .pipe(
    map((kv) => {
      // use object destructuring to get a new reference instead of
      // JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(something))
      const jsonObject = { ...kv };
      return Object.keys(jsonObject).map(key => ({ id: key, value: jsonObject[key] });
    }),
  ).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```